# Repeated Measures Model with Autoregression (SAS and R)

Tags: r, sas, statistics, autoregressive-models

I am attempting to match a repeated measures model with autoregression that was originally fit using SAS. The SAS code is as follows...

```
 *** Repeated Measures ANOVA Analysis ***;                                                       
 ***    for cs covariance structure ***;                                                         
 options pageno=1;                                                                               
 ods output dimensions=work._dim                                                                 
                   (where=(ddescr ? 'Covariance') rename=(value=parms 
descr=ddescr))         
        fitStatistics = work._fit;                                                           
proc mixed data=_proj_.Set_bisc1_set info;                                                      
class SET;                                                                                   
model ABS_PIN_DIFF = DAY SET DAY*SET / ddfm=satterth htype=3 solution                        
   outp=WORK._PRED;                                                                          
repeated SET / sub=DAY type=cs;                                                              
run;                                                                                            
** Accumulate info criteria for multiple cov structures **;                                     
data work._ic;                                                                                  
length label $ 128;                                                                          
retain aic bic ll2 . label;                                                                  
label = "Compound symmetry";                                                                 
if _n_ = 1 then set work._dim;                                                               
set work._fit end=_last_;                                                                    
select (scan(descr,1,' '));                                                                  
   when ("AIC") aic = value;                                                                 
   when ("BIC") bic = value;                                                                 
   when ("-2")  ll2 = value;                                                                 
   otherwise delete;                                                                         
   end;                                                                                      
if _last_ then output;                                                                       
drop descr value;                                                                            
run;                                                                                            
data work._ll2; set work._ic; drop aic bic;                                                     
rename parms=parms_0 ll2 = ll2_0;                                                            
run;                                                                                         
proc append base=work._icall data=work._ic;                                                     
proc datasets nolist library=work;                                                              
   delete _dim _fit _ic;                                                                        
run; quit;                                                                                      
goptions reset=all device=WIN;
```

And the output I am trying to match is...

```
                                    The Mixed Procedure

                                     Model Information

                   Data Set                     _PROJ_.SET_BISC1_SET     
                   Dependent Variable           Abs_Pin_Diff             
                   Covariance Structure         Autoregressive           
                   Subject Effect               Day                      
                   Estimation Method            REML                     
                   Residual Variance Method     Profile                  
                   Fixed Effects SE Method      Model-Based              
                   Degrees of Freedom Method    Satterthwaite            


                                  Class Level Information

                     Class    Levels    Values

                     SET           3    BISC1SET1 BISC1SET2 BISC1SET3 


                                        Dimensions

                            Covariance Parameters             2
                            Columns in X                      8
                            Columns in Z                      0
                            Subjects                          9
                            Max Obs Per Subject               3


                                  Number of Observations

                        Number of Observations Read              73
                        Number of Observations Used              27
                        Number of Observations Not Used          46


                                     Iteration History

                Iteration    Evaluations    -2 Res Log Like       Criterion

                        0              1       218.92633483                
                        1              2       213.69046030      0.00000316
                        2              1       213.69018242      0.00000000


                                 Convergence criteria met.                    


                               Covariance Parameter Estimates

                              Cov Parm     Subject    Estimate

                              AR(1)        Day          0.5767
                              Residual                  183.76
                                    The Mixed Procedure

                                      Fit Statistics

                           -2 Res Log Likelihood           213.7
                           AIC (smaller is better)         217.7
                           AICC (smaller is better)        218.4
                           BIC (smaller is better)         218.1


                              Null Model Likelihood Ratio Test

                                DF    Chi-Square      Pr > ChiSq

                                 1          5.24          0.0221


                                 Solution for Fixed Effects

                                               Standard
      Effect          SET          Estimate       Error      DF    t Value    Pr > |t|

      Intercept                     11.6248      8.2068    13.7       1.42      0.1790
      Day                          0.006454    0.009346    13.7       0.69      0.5014
      SET             BISC1SET1     -1.7517      9.4816    18.5      -0.18      0.8554
      SET             BISC1SET2    -14.1656      7.5510    13.2      -1.88      0.0829
      SET             BISC1SET3           0           .       .        .         .    
      Day*SET         BISC1SET1     0.01310     0.01080    18.5       1.21      0.2403
      Day*SET         BISC1SET2    0.009653    0.008599    13.2       1.12      0.2816
      Day*SET         BISC1SET3           0           .       .        .         .    


                               Type 3 Tests of Fixed Effects

                                     Num     Den
                       Effect         DF      DF    F Value    Pr > F

                       Day             1    7.08       3.40    0.1072
                       SET             2    13.3       2.57    0.1135
                       Day*SET         2    13.3       0.84    0.4520
```

It appears they are using a "Repeated Measures ANOVA Analysis" which a far as I know does not exist in R. The models I have attempted to fit are...

```
trymodel3<-gls(Abs_Pin_Diff~Day+SET+Days*SET, 
           correlation = corCAR1(form=~Day|SET),
           data = Andrea3, na.action = na.exclude, method="REML")
trymodel4<-lme(Abs_Pin_Diff~Day+SET+Day*SET, random =~Day|SET, 
           correlation = corCAR1(form=~Day|SET),
           data = Andrea3, na.action = na.exclude, method="REML")
```

The output I get is slightly different than that produced by SAS. Consequently, I am wondering if this has to do with differences in the two programs or if I have failed to capture the entirety of the SAS models in R. My data looks something like this...

```
dput(Andrea3)
structure(list(SET = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("BISC1SET1", "BISC1SET2", "BISC1SET3"
), class = "factor"), Day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), Abs_Pin_Diff = c(0, 
-7.0175, 25.2675, 47.4775, 33.8325, 26.605, 37.7725, 27.1425, 
26.785, 0, -8.0575, -6.06, 33.23, 2.4275, 4.7975, 23.6675, 13.5, 
19.875, 0, -1.5775, 31.2025, 34.6925, 16.87, 14.125, 23.0575, 
11.6675, 17.1475)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), vars = "SET", drop = TRUE, class 
= c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: *"It appears they are using a "Repeated Measures ANOVA Analysis which a far as I know does not exist in R."* That's not correct. Generally you can do RM ANOVA in R with a variety of packages: `nlme`, `lme4`, `ez` to name a few popular ones. I'm not familiar with SAS, so perhaps you can provide some more general details on the model and in particular on its autoregressive component.

Comment: Also perhaps helpful is [this link](http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer#heterogenous-ar1) with specific examples on how to fit nested-effect models (equivalent to RM ANOVAs) with various autoregressive residual structures.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have found some documentation of an rmanova() function online but my console says the function cannot be found. A for some more details about the SAS model, it is a repeated measure ANOVA with a autoregressive order 1 co-variance structure. The subject is SET and the repeated measure is Day. Finally, the estimation method is REML.

Comment: There seems to be an `rmanova` function in package `WRS2`, but I'm not familiar with it. It's probably a good idea to share the output of the SAS model, so we have something to work towards. I will have a play around, but it may take a bit of time. Also take a look at the link in my second comment, which gives examples how to implement AR(1) residuals in `nlme::lme`.

Comment: I am looking through the tutorial now, thus far it has been by far the most helpful I have found, thank you!!

Comment: I will add the output of the SAS code to my original post

Comment: I've been playing around with various `lme` models, but I'm still struggling to understand your SAS output. So it's difficult to compare the `lme` output with results from your SAS model. From what I understand `model ABS_PIN_DIFF = DAY SET DAY*SET` defines your model of the form `Abs_Pin_Diff ~ Day * SET` (in R's formula syntax `Day * SET` is short for `Day + SET + Day:SET`); so far so good. But where in the SAS output are the parameter estimates for the three `SET` levels and for `Day`? The block `Covariance Parameter Estimates` only seems to give an estimate for the autoregressive term.

Comment: I added the entirety of the SAS output. It seems as though it did not all make it during my first edit.

Comment: Old SAS guy turned R enthusiast here - that is random effects mixed model predicting Abs_Pin_Dif from Set, Day, and the linear combination of Set and Day, with Set repeating within group, across Day using a compound symmetric covariance structure. There is an issue with the convergence given the estimates in the Fixed Effects section of BISC1SET3. Also, Day as a random effect doesn’t seem to do anything when analyzing the covariance parameter estimates. That is, it explaining very little variance in the DV. All of this said, we can recreate this model in R using the packages listed above.

Comment: Wow thanks for the input! It sounds like my models in R were on the right track. Do you have any insight as to whether trymodel3 or trymodel4 is more accurately recreating the model fit in SAS? Or how they could be modified to do so?

Comment: In addition, I see the SAS code uses a compound symmetry co-variance structure while the output corresponds to a co-variance structure of auto-regressive order 1. In my R model I am attempting to use an auto-regressive order 1 structure